# how to hide mainMenu panel when opening new one

Tags: java, swing

so my problem is that I had change toolbar into buttons in my program, nothing hard so I just add them and that worked but my Jpanel did not show op it was showing only main menu layout I think other jpanel was behind it that's why it didn't work. after some hrs of trying to fix it I have this:

```
package ScotiaAirlines.src;

public class MainMenu {
private static JFrame frame;
public static AirlineManager AirlineMgr = new AirlineManager(); // get access to class manager for to use methods that are needed for the app

public static PassengerPanel PassengerPanel = null;
public static FlightsPanel FlightsPanel = null;
public static BookPanel BookPanel;

public static AirlineManager getAirlineMgr() {
    return AirlineMgr;
}

public static JFrame getFrame() {
    return frame;
}

private static void enableMenus(Boolean enable) {

    }


public static void displayNewPassenger() {
    enableMenus(false);

    if (PassengerPanel == null) {
        PassengerPanel = new PassengerPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(PassengerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    PassengerPanel.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void hideNewPassenger() {
    enableMenus(true);

    PassengerPanel.setVisible(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void displayFlights() {
    enableMenus(false);

    FlightsPanel = new FlightsPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(FlightsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    FlightsPanel.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void hideFlights() {
    enableMenus(true);

    FlightsPanel.setVisible(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void displayBook() {
    enableMenus(false);

    BookPanel = new BookPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(BookPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    BookPanel.setVisible(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void hideBook() {
    enableMenus(true);

    BookPanel.setVisible(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainMenu window = new MainMenu();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public MainMenu() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);


    JButton mntmNewMenuItem = new JButton("Book Flight");
    mntmNewMenuItem.setBounds(276, 0, 128, 23);
    mntmNewMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayBook();
            frame.getContentPane().setVisible(false);
        }
    });

    frame.getContentPane().add(mntmNewMenuItem);



    JButton mntmNewPassenger = new JButton("Passenger");
    mntmNewPassenger.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayNewPassenger();
        }
    });
    mntmNewPassenger.setBounds(0, 0, 128, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(mntmNewPassenger);

    JButton mntmNewFlight = new JButton("Flight");
    mntmNewFlight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayFlights();
        }
    });
    mntmNewFlight.setBounds(138, 0, 128, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(mntmNewFlight);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);


}
}
```

Picture of main menu

[image]

ps. I had to delete all imports here don't know why, it didn't let me. any idea what to do here?

Comment: Use [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) Luke

Comment: cant use that teacher wants only absolute layout and then buttons on it. so toolbars or cardlayout cant be use. just buttons

Comment: *"teacher wants only absolute layout"* Find a new teacher. This one is incompetent and cannot teach you what is worth knowing. Good luck with it. Few will try to help kludge a broken approach.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about fixing an approach that is fundamentally broken, rather than using the tool (`CardLayout`) designed for the job.

Comment: `I had change toolbar into buttons in my program` - so use a JToolBar, the Swing component designed for this purpose. Read the section from the Swing